# How to save a image to a directory in java

Tags: java, image, save

So I have drawn this image with my drawing-project but dont know how to save it to a directory.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KDzvF.png)

Could you help me out pls.

Comment: let us know what you have tried. Did you try google?

Comment: where are you reading image from HTTP, local disk, ftp ?

Comment: Could you add a link to the code or post some of the code with your question?  This link shows some guidelines on providing a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1):

If I understood right,you can drag and drop a picture to your IDE,first you can create a new folder(press right click on the project then `new` then `source folder`,this is for Eclipse)and then look what I use(if you are using Swing):

```
 JLabel label = new JLabel("");
        Image img = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("imageName.jpg")).getImage();
        label.setIcon(new ImageIcon(img));
        label.setBounds(15, -228, 688, 391);
        frame.getContentPane().add(label);
```

Comment: where do i have to write this ?